# Run bat file in c# with .exe and .def code

Tags: c#, process, exe, batch-file, function

How can I run a bat file in C# that has the following code:

```
tekla_dstv2dxf.exe -cfg tekla_dstv2dxf_metric.def -m batch -f *.nc1
```

or alternatively replicate that code in my c# program.
Using this code executes the bat file but the bat file doesn't work.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\0TeklaBatchProcess\1-SCAD_Issue_Processing\DXF\tekla_dstv2dxf_metric_conversion.bat");
```

The bat file works fine if I double click it, just not through my program.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, worked it out by chance. Code below:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "tekla_dstv2dxf.exe";
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\0TeklaBatchProcess\1-SCAD_Issue_Processing\DXF";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-cfg tekla_dstv2dxf_metric.def -m batch -f *.nc1";
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the command arguments directly in the Start method parameters:

`Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "www.northwindtraders.com");`

so

`Process.Start("tekla_dstv2dxf.exe", "-cfg tekla_dstv2dxf_metric.def -m batch -f *.nc1");`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx

Comment: Hi, it just starts and ends immediately. Is it not accepting the code?

Answer (score 0):

Use System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo

Comment: Tried that too but still doesn't work. I think it's not accepting the commands